# Load file downloaded iOS app created in Unity

Tags: c#, ios, json, xcode, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to load a json file downloaded and saved in the persistentDataPath of an iOS device. The download and save works great. However I think I have big issues to load the file. In fact when I try to compile the project in Xcode I have some errors messages.

First here is my C# code :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ReadJson : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text City;
    public Text Temperature;
    public Image Weather;
    public Text WeatherUrl;

    [System.Serializable]
    public class CityInfo 
    {
        public string name;
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class CurrentCondition
    {
        public string date; 
        public string hour; 
        public int tmp; 
        public int wnd_spd; 
        public int wnd_gust; 
        public string wnd_dir; 
        public double pressure; 
        public int humidity; 
        public string condition; 
        public string icon; 
        public string icon_big;
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class RootObject
    {
        public CityInfo city_info;
        public CurrentCondition current_condition;
    }

    void Start () {

        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        File.Delete(Path.Combine (Application.persistentDataPath, "myjson.json"));
        client.DownloadFile ("http://www.myjsonurl", Path.Combine (Application.persistentDataPath, "myjson.json"));

        TextAsset asset = Resources.Load (Path.Combine (Application.dataPath + "/Documents", "myjson")) as TextAsset;

        RootObject m = JsonUtility.FromJson<RootObject> (asset.text);

        City.text = m.city_info.name;
        Temperature.text = (m.current_condition.tmp).ToString();

    }
}
```

And now the xcode console :

```
2016-10-21 17:01:20.766001 json[1404:516674] [DYMTLInitPlatform] platform initialization successful

2016-10-21 17:01:20.929950 json[1404:516508] -> registered mono modules 0xb95f70
2016-10-21 17:01:21.356590 json[1404:516508] You've implemented -[<UIApplicationDelegate> application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:], but you still need to add "remote-notification" to the list of your supported UIBackgroundModes in your Info.plist.
-> applicationDidFinishLaunching()
2016-10-21 17:01:21.452967 json[1404:516508] Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled
2016-10-21 17:01:21.453369 json[1404:516508] Metal API Validation Enabled
-> applicationDidBecomeActive()
Init: screen size 750x1334
Initializing Metal device caps
Initialize engine version: 5.3.4f1 (fdbb5133b820)
UnloadTime: 1.705875 ms
Salut/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/51A2490E-94EB-4904-9F2E-112AD5632A98/Documents

(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 37)

NullReferenceException: A null value was found where an object instance was required.


(Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)

Setting up 1 worker threads for Enlighten.
  Thread -> id: 19f17000 -> priority: 1
```

If someone has an idea. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You said that the big issue is loading the file. Then you said when you try to compile the project in Xcode, you have some errors messages...Which one is your problem? Does this compile? If it does not compile, then this has nothing to do with loading the json file.

Comment: The project compiles great, but after the app loading, it crashs displaying the error message. So the problem comes from the json file loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is on this line:

```
TextAsset asset = Resources.Load(Path.Combine(Application.dataPath + "/Documents", "myjson")) as TextAsset;
```

I don't think you understand how and when to use `Resources.Load`. If you want to use the `Resources.Load` function, you must create a special folder from the Editor. This folder should be at `<ProjectDirectory>/Assets/Resources`. You can **only** put/write stuff into this folder from the Editor. You can't do it after build on iOS. It becomes *read only* after you build it. This special folder can then be read with the `Resources.Load` function.

Replacing:

```
TextAsset asset = Resources.Load(Path.Combine(Application.dataPath + "/Documents", "myjson")) as TextAsset;
```

with

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "myjson.json"));
RootObject m = JsonUtility.FromJson<RootObject>(text);
City.text = m.city_info.name;
Temperature.text = (m.current_condition.tmp).ToString();
```

Should solve your problem.

Another API that should not be using is `WebClient`. Unless you have a good reason to use that, you shouldn't. You should either use the [`WWW`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) or [`UnityWebRequest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest.html)(newer and recommended) API.

This is what your code should look like without `WebClient`:

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(DownloadAndloadJson());
}

IEnumerator DownloadAndloadJson()
{
    string url = "http://www.myjsonurl";

    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
    yield return www.Send();

    if (www.isError)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        //Sucessfully downloaded the Json File
        Debug.Log("Json: " + www.downloadHandler.text);

        string jsonFile = www.downloadHandler.text;

        //Delete old json file. Don't know why but this was in your original code
        File.Delete(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "myjson.json"));

        //Save the downloaded data as File
        File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "myjson.json"), jsonFile);

        //Load the downloaded data 
        string text = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "myjson.json"));

        Debug.Log(text);
        RootObject m = JsonUtility.FromJson<RootObject>(text);
        City.text = m.city_info.name;
        Temperature.text = (m.current_condition.tmp).ToString();
    }
}
```

If you have problems please update to Unity 5.4. The `UnityWebRequest` API should be used for this and it was introduced in 5.3 but bugs were fixed in 5.4. You need `using UnityEngine.Networking;` to use `UnityWebRequest`.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works just great replacing the code like you said. Thanks also for the second solution, I will try but first I need to update Unity ;-)

Comment: You don't have to update Unity for second solution since that is supported in Unity 5.3 but I recommend to update if there is a problem with it. Your current solution with `WebClient`  freezes your app while downloading stuff. You probably won't notice that now but when the data to download is large, you will notice it. There are other reasons such as App store now banning apps that doesn't support https. This version of Unity with `WebClient` does not support it so your app will be rejected. You are welcome!

Comment: Ok I just tested with your second solution. Works great. Thanks again and again. You are right regarding the App store conditions. Better like this so. At this point no issue with Unity 5.3

Comment: Nice. Happy coding!